# Combining foreach and using

Tags: c#, foreach, idisposable, using

I'm iterating over a [ManagementObjectCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectcollection) ( which is part of the WMI interface).

However, the important thing is, the following line of code. :

```
foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
    //code here
}
```

The point is that [ManagementObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject) also implements IDisposable, so I would like to put the "result" variable in a using block. Any idea on how to do this, without getting too weird or complex?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
foreach (ManagementObject result in results) using (result)
{
    //code here
}
```

Assigning the variable outside the `using` block is not normally good practice because the resource would be disposed of but could stay in scope. It would, however, result in clearer code here because you can nest the `using` statement against the `foreach`.

Comment: I think Dispose method has be invoked by a site where "result" object where created

Comment: No, Dispose can be called anywhere.

Comment: foreach automatically call Dispose on Enumerable if it is IDisposable, so first using unnecessary

Comment: @Alexander foreach will call Dispose on the Enumerator which would be returned by ManagementObjectCollection GetEnumerator() method. Dispose will NOT be called on ManagementObjectCollection object.

Comment: What will happen if //Code here throws an exception?! all the remaining objects in results will not be Disposed, and you have a memory leak!!

Answer (score 24):

You could do the following.

```
foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
  using (result)
  {
    // Your code goes here.
  }
}
```

The neat thing about C# is how different language constructs can share scoped code blocks. That means you could do the following to eliminate the nesting.

```
foreach (ManagementObject result in results) using (result)
{
  // Your code goes here.
}
```

It is also useful to know that the `foreach` construct will call `Dispose` on the target `IEnumerator` as well. The code above would be equivalent to.

```
IEnumerator enumerator = results.GetEnumerator()
try
{
  while (enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    ManagementObject result = (ManagementObject)enumerator.Current;
    IDisposable disposable = (IDisposable)result;
    try
    {
      // Your code goes here.
    }
    finally
    {
      disposable.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
finally
{
  IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
  if (disposable != null)
  {
    disposable.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a cleaner syntax:

```
foreach (ManagementObject obj in result) using (obj)
{
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: I like the syntax but Visual Studio screws up the formatting (it adds an extra tab to the block).

Answer (score 4):

`ManagementObjectCollection` is itself `IDisposable`...

So it would be...

```
using (var results = ..)
{
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        using (result)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not call Dispose() on each `ManagementObject`, only on the `ManagementObjectCollection` itself.

Comment: To be very padantic it would call `Dispose` on both the `ManagementObjectCollection` and the `IEnumerator` used in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a nice neat syntax via extension methods and enumerators.  First, define this in a `public static class` somewhere in your code:

```
public static IEnumerable<ManagementObject> WithDisposal(
                    this ManagementObjectCollection list)
{
    using (list)
    {
        foreach (var obj in list)
        {
            using (obj)
            {
                yield return obj;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

... which you can then use with just this:

```
foreach (var obj in /*get the results*/.WithDisposal())
{
    // ...
}
```

Though bear in mind that if you use `WithDisposal` then you won't be able to save any of the objects for future use.

Comment: I like this. You could even make it generic with type constraints to `IDisposable`.

Comment: You could, but this is definitely a special case.  Normally disposing a collection of disposable objects should dispose of its contained objects too.  (I've defined a generic `DisposableList` in my code for this purpose.)

Comment: There is one further caveat -- this will only dispose everything if you actually fully traverse the enumeration returned.  If you stop partway through then the collection will still be disposed but any objects you haven't looked at yet will not be.  This applies to most of the other answers posted here as well, of course.

Answer (score -1):

It will look weird - iterating over array and disposing each of the objects it contains. If you really want to do this, use

```
foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
    try {
        // code here
    }
    finally {
        result.Dispose();
    }
}

/* do not forget to, or to not reuse results!
results = null; 
results.Clear();
*/
```

which is exactly what `using` statement does.

Comment: Because this is "exactly what a using statement does" is why you should not do this.